# NullPointerException in logcat with no clues

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am violating best practices here trying to figure this out, so to start off with, I realize that and I appreciate any insight. I'm making something simple that relies on a lot of Dialog calls. Nothing fancy, not calling a lot of Fragments. My game will require no permissions.

With the backstory out of the way, I'm getting this NPE:

```
06-13 01:29:03.581  24690-24690/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 24690
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:309)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17388)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5353)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17388)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5353)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17388)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2217)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1354)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1553)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6473)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my very flat app, I do this:

```
public static MainActivity ACTIVITY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ACTIVITY = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        ACTIVITY.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Then I do a bunch of stuff that works fine. The problem is, I call a class that does a battle event:

```
FightEvent thisFight = new FightEvent(this);
    ALLOWSAVE = false;
    thisFight.doFightEvent();
```

In that class, when the fight starts, I do:

```
ACTIVITY.setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight);
```

When I exit the fight, I do:

```
ACTIVITY.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**PLOT TWIST:** This all works fine in older versions. I'm trying to make my game 100% compatible back to API 8.

Works great in API 8. API 19-22, not so much.

Help?

Comment: "public static MainActivity ACTIVITY;" is receipt for trouble

Comment: I know. I'm having a lot of sad.

Comment: Just googling, found this if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318191/nullpointerexception-in-framelayout-onmeasure

Comment: @racraman, yep. Done that. No dice.

Comment: For the record, "public static MainActivity ACTIVITY" is part of what I'm doing to track down the problem. I'm pretty much calling ACTIVITY.<blah> before everything View related, and still have no idea why this NPE is happening. Force-stepping my way through the code also provides no clues. :(

Comment: I guess you're using an IDE to develop your program, so you can try to open the `FrameLayout.java` and look at line 309 to see what might be `null` there. I guess you forgot to set some kind of (new) parameter in one of your layout files.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that @Tom. I have put a breakpoint on line 309 there and I don't get any help. Every time it breaks, it contains MainActivity.